# How to initiate a correct reset of a Tracking Event Processor

Tags: axon

I am trying to use Axon's `TrackingEventProcessor` to replay our events. 
While resetting the token, I am getting an `UnableToClaimTokenException`, since the service runs in a distributed setup.

Is there any way to solve this issue without using Axon Server?

Answer (score 0):

Axon Server has nothing to do with the occurrence of the `UnableToClaimTokenException`, Axon Server just greatly simplifies the process of initiating a replay.

As the exception **and** javadoc of the `TrackingEventProcessor` state, you will need to stop *all* instances of a given `TrackingEventProcessor` prior to initiating a replay.

Thus, in a distributed set up, you will have to stop each and every duplication of the given `TrackingEventProcessor` prior to being able to actual call `resetTokens` on one of them.

Without Axon Server, that means you will have to create your own endpoints or CLI within your application to stop the given processors. To simplify this, you would essentially want to have a centralized dashboard which shows all occurrence of a given `TrackingEventProcessor`.
This is exactly what Axon Server is, hence simplifying the process tremendously.

Regardless, it's definitely doable to create this yourself.
Thus, when it comes to triggering a replay, you will first shut down each instance of the TEP prior to a reset.